# Recursion related exception: Unable to get property 'tag' of undefined or null reference

Tags: elm

I receive the following error after performing an HTTP post:

> Unable to get property 'tag' of undefined or null reference

I believe the error occurs when executing the following decoder function:

```
sourceDecoder : Decoder JsonSource
sourceDecoder =
    Decode.map5 JsonSource
        ...
        (field "Links" providerLinksDecoder)
```

**Decoder Dependencies:**

```
providerLinksDecoder : Decoder JsonProviderLinks
providerLinksDecoder =
    Decode.map JsonLinkFields
        (field "Links" <| Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> linkDecoder)))
        |> Decode.map JsonProviderLinks

linkDecoder : Decoder JsonLink
linkDecoder =
    Decode.map6 JsonLink
        (field "Profile" profileDecoder)
        ...

profileDecoder : Decoder JsonProfile
profileDecoder =
    Decode.map7 JsonProfile
        ...
        (field "Sources" <| Decode.list (Decode.lazy (\_ -> sourceDecoder)))
```

**Appendix:**

```
type JsonProviderLinks
    = JsonProviderLinks JsonLinkFields


type alias JsonLinkFields =
    { links : List JsonLink
    }
```

The source code can be found on [here](https://github.com/bizmonger/Nikeza/blob/da07dd083210d93be17789aa2c0b7e3f551dfc02/Client/app/Services/Gateway.elm).

Note: I attempted to research this error and came across this [page](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1591).
As a result, I attempted to use the Decode.lazy function. However, my attempt failed.

Comment: Are you able to include a [short, self-contained, compilable example?](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I updated the post to show the essentials.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of decoders that rely on other decoders in your examples. You've changed some of them to use `Decode.lazy`, but not all, and that error you've received will happen when there's some out of control recursion.

You don't need a list to be able to use `lazy`. Try - as a first step towards debugging, at least - to change *all* decoders that reference other decoders to use `Decode.lazy`. For example:

```elm
sourceDecoder : Decoder JsonSource
sourceDecoder =
    Decode.map5 JsonSource
        ...
        (field "Links" (Decode.lazy (\_ -> providerLinksDecoder)))
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/873 and https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/master/hints/bad-recursion.md